# Selenium Webdriver - Java: I want to switch on new opening pop

Tags: selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I want to switch to the popup window but don't know how to do it.  Please help if anyone knows how to do it.

For more details I've attached a picture here.

[image]

Comment: "here" doesnt contain any attachment,please edit ur question

Comment: Can you show us the pop-up html code?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `driver.switchTo();`,but if you want to keep the code simple,u can just wait for the required element in the pop up and continue with operations..

for example,
If the operation is to **Enter data into account input field**

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Account"))).sendKeys("1234");
```

the above code will wait until the pop up appears and then enters data into the account(*here i assumed the id is **Account***) field..

Answer (score 0):

best way which i found is : driver.switchTo().frame(0);

Answer (score 0):

You can use `driver.switchTo()` function. Here is an simple example.

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.abc.com/");

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.findElement(By.linkText("New")).click();
    System.out.println("After clicking on New");
    Set<String> windowHandlesAfter = driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> itAfter = windowHandlesAfter.iterator();

    String parent = itAfter.next();
    String child = itAfter.next();     
    driver.switchTo().window(child);
```